# What 'nitty gritty' means in this context exactly?

Tags: vocabulary, idioms

I understand 'nitty gritty' is something specific; the essential thing.  Is it also applied in these following lines?

"correcting the average amount of errors that I am presented with is too nitty gritty for me."

Comment: As an aside, you'd probably want to say _number of errors_, not _amount of errors_.

Answer (score 2):

'nitty-gritty' means the basic facts or detailed issues. A common phrase is

> let's get down to the **nitty-gritty**.

for example

> I can't tell why our new product new product stopped working. So let's get down to the **nitty-gritty** and find out what happened.

meaning doing a detailed examination of all the facts related to the product, to find out what failed.

Or if you were having relationship problems with someone close to you, you could say

> Let's get down to the **nitty-gritty** and figure this out.

In your example:

> Correcting the average amount of errors that I am presented with is too **nitty gritty** for me.

may be OK but it sounds strange to me. I would say

> Correcting the average amount of errors that I am presented with is too **difficult** for me.

maybe meaning it's too hard but also could mean it takes too much time.

Comment: Can I say "The nitty-gritty is, ..." as an alternative to "Essentially, ..."?

Comment: @user3169 Okay, because the subject in this context is too technical ('difficult' as you revised). Thank you.

Comment: _Difficult_ is one choice, but only a good one if you want to suggest that correcting the errors is "difficult" for some reason. Other words you could consider are _too onerous_ (if the number is simply too high) or even _too detailed_ (if the errors are insignificant and therefore not a good investment of time).

Comment: The phrase "nitty-gritty" is very informal, so be sure that you consider that before using it in a given situation.

Answer (score 0):

The "nitty gritty" is the most BASIC stuff.

"correcting the average amount of errors that I am presented with is too nitty gritty for me."
 That is,  "it is too BASIC for me."